# Passing Scala Option[List[_]] to Java JDBC Array using statement.setArray()

Tags: java, arrays, scala, jdbc, callable-statement

I'm trying to build an interface from Scala to JDBC callableStatements. For the most part, it's straightforward, except for `Lists`.

I need to be able to take a Scala `List` of some type, and convert it into a Java Array that can be passed to `statement.setArray(type, array)` and I'm not having any luck (partly because I don't know Java and JDBC very well).

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
for (parameter <- ps.parameters) {
    case GPArrayIn(None, t) => callableStatement.setNull(index, t)
    case GPIn(v: Some[_], Types.INTEGER) => callableStatement.setInt(index, v.get.asInstanceOf[Int])
    case GPIn(v: Some[_], Types.VARCHAR | Types.LONGVARCHAR) => callableStatement.setString(index, v.get.asInstanceOf[String])
    case GPArrayIn(v: Some[List[_]], Types.INTEGER) => callableStatement.setArray(Types.INTEGER, ???? )
    case GPArrayIn(v: Some[List[_]], Types.VARCHAR | Types.LONGVARCHAR) => callableStatement.setArray(Types.VARCHAR, ???? )
    ...
```

It's pretty straightforward for simple values but when it comes to the `setArray()` calls I'm stuck.

Any advice would be sorely appreciated. Been stuck on this for *hours...*

Comment: Be aware that support for Array is spotty at best in most drivers (if the database itself supports them at all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setArray` takes a `java.sql.Array` as described in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray%28int,%20java.sql.Array%29):

```
void setArray(int parameterIndex, Array x)
          throws SQLException
```

You can create one with:

```
sqlArray = connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", regularJavaArray);
```

which is of type:

```
Array createArrayOf(String typeName, Object[] elements)
                throws SQLException
```

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html) doc for examples and explanation if needed.

Bottom line: you need to convert Scala collection to java array if it's not an array already, then convert that Java array to SQL array using `createArrayOf`. It will do some under the hood magic to map that data to SQL ARRAY.

As for the pattern matching and extraction, you can use something like that:

```
scala> val numbers = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
numbers: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> def arrayMatcher[T](maybeArray:  Option[Array[T]]): String =
     |     maybeArray match {
     |       case Some(a: Array[Int]) => a.mkString(",")
     |       case Some(b: Array[String]) => b.mkString("-")
     |       case None => "no array"
     |       case _ => "no match"
     |     }
arrayMatcher: [T](maybeArray: Option[Array[T]])String

scala> arrayMatcher(Some(numbers))
res0: String = 1,2,3,4

scala> arrayMatcher(None)
res1: String = no array

scala> arrayMatcher(Some(numbers map(_.toString)))
res2: String = 1-2-3-4

scala> arrayMatcher(Some(Array(1.2, 3.4)))
res3: String = no match

scala> arrayMatcher(Some(List(1, 2)))
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Some[List[Int]]
 required: Option[Array[?]]
              arrayMatcher(Some(List(1, 2)))
                               ^
```

To convert a list to array use:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).toArray
res6: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks... This much I'm aware of (although you use `createArrayOf(string, array)` whereas I'm using `createArray(intType, array)` – not sure if that's an important difference. Problem is, I can't seem to get my Option[List[_]] instances converted into a Java Array. That's the part that I am chiefly stuck on. Thanks for confirming how the Java/JDBC end of it works though.

Comment: Oh, do you mean the pattern match itself with extraction?

Comment: That gets me closer... Unfortunately just passing a Scala `Array` to JDBC's `createArray()` doesn't work... Tried a cast using `asInstanceOf[java.sql.Array]` but that results in `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.sql.Array`... Still working on it.

Comment: Scala array can be used in place of Java array. However, in your case you need `java.sql.Array` which is not the same as plain Java array `[]`. Thus you need to convert scala/java array to `java.sql.Array` as I explained in my answer.

Comment: Yes... and that is non-trivial. We posted this to support, and got back the following regarding how to go about the conversion: `callableStatement.setArray(index, callableStatement.getConnection.createArrayOf("NUMERIC", v.get.toArray[Any].asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]]))` although we are still working on implementing it.

Comment: @Zac, that's similar to what I was saying except for the casting part. How about a completely different approach: create a java class that deals with it and call it from scala. Basically a Java wrapper which can be even compiled with regular scala build tools like maven or sbt. Unless the whole problem is not in conversion but in some buggy/non-portable JDBC driver implementation. Please post what you find out, I'm very curious.